# Mail delivered via server IP not associated with sender

Tags: smtp

When a **sunbirdinc.com** account sends an email to an **earthlink.net** address, the following message bounces back:

> *ToSomeone*@earthlink.net
> host mx1.earthlink.net [209.86.93.226]
> SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM: <*FromSomeone*@sunbirdinc.com>:
> 550 IP 199.79.63.190 is blocked by EarthLink. Go to earthlink.net/block for details.

Why/how would this 199 IP be delivering the message to earthlink? The sunbirdinc.com mail server is different. The only association I can find is **webhostbox.net**.

DNS info:

> MX: sunbirdinc.com --> sunbirdinc.com
> A: sunbirdinc.com --> 208.91.199.49
> PTR: 208.91.199.49 --> bh-26.webhostbox.net
>
> PTR: 199.79.63.190 --> 199.79.63-190.confluence-networks.com
> A: confluence-networks.com --> 208.91.198.88
> PTR: 208.91.198.88 --> md-75.webhostbox.net

Side note:
Earthlink doesn't like the 199 IP because it's flagged by Cloudmark.
Cloudmark doesn't like it (at least partly) because the PTR domain is generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to whois, both 208.91.199.x and 199.79.63.x are registered to Confluence Networks. So it seems they are just using a different IP for outgoing mail than for incoming mail, which is perfectly justified.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address is being blocked by Earthlink

An SMTP server can deliver for many domains. If one or more users are registered as SPAM offenders you can become a victim of someone else's actions.  The sender can complain to their provider as well as use SPF records and other methods to properly identify their email.

https://support.earthlink.net/articles/email/email-blocked-by-earthlink.php
Earthlink Article ID: 35652

Excerpt from article- read full article for complete details.

Check a DNSBlacklists to see of the IP is a known offender or notify Earthlink to update their records or get a more detailed explanation for the reason for the block

One such blacklist is 
http://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php

Hope this helps.